# spark SQL GROUP BY aggregation raises error "list index out of range"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark 1.5.0 with two columns. The following query works correctly:
`sqlContext.sql("select id, value from table").show()`

But doing aggregations fails:

`sqlContext.sql("select id, count(value) from table group by id").show()`

Returns an error:

`WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 10.0: Traceback`...

`IndexError: list Index out of range`

I used `count` on purpose do exclude the possiblity of wrong type. All columns are regarded as strings (though some are numbers).
Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: Problem is most likely somewhere upstream but unless you provide enough details (code you've used to create table, full traceback) it will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the reason was that the dataframe that originated the table had been created with an incomplete row, such as:

```
a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, "a"), (2, )], ["id", "value"])
```

If it's the case, maybe you can try:

```
sqlContext.sql("select id, count(coalesce(value, '')) from table group by id").show()
```

or

```
sqlContext.sql("select id, count(*) from table group by id").show()
```